# Can I use writeStream.bytesWritten with pipe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, fs

I want to be able to monitor the speed of a copy using node.js and `pipe` methods so that I can display a progress bar, a speed indicator and eventually a time estimation.

For the moment, while looking through some references, I suppose that I'll have to play with [writeStream.bytesWritten](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_writestream_byteswritten), but I am not sure how to correctly use it: **does it works with `pipe` ? Or do I have to use `writeableStream.write();` ?**

---

**Some context :**

As I need to copy several files, I use a `do ... while` loop and increment a counter each time a copy is launched. It works fine, but I am unable to use `writeStream.bytesWritten` to monitor transfer rate.

Below is the code I'm currently using, `console.log(firstCopy.bytesWritten);` returns `0` twice:

```
//Launch copy process
do {
  let readableStream = fs.createReadStream(fileList[i]);//This is the source file
  let firstCopy = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(copyPathOne, fileName[i])),
    secondCopy = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(copyPathTwo, fileName[i]));//These are the targets

  readableStream.pipe(firstCopy);//We launch the first copy
  readableStream.pipe(secondCopy);//And the second copy
  console.log(firstCopy.bytesWritten);//Here we monitor the amount of bytes written
  ++i;//Then we increment the counter

} while (i < fileList.length);//And we repeat the process while the counter is < to the number of files
```

I've also tried:

```
console.log(writeStream.bytesWritten(firstCopy));//Error: writeStream is not defined
```

**Why do you use `do ... while` and not `forEach` ?**

I'm iterating through an array. I could have used `forEach`, but as I do not clearly understand how does it works, I prefered to use `do ... while` . Also, I thought that it would be a simple method to copy each file, and that it would wait for the end of the copy (the `pipe`) as said here:

> An expression evaluated after each pass through the loop. If condition evaluates to true, the statement is re-executed.
>  *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you are trying to do something like this:

```
const wstream = fs.createWriteStream('myFileToWriteTo'); 
const rstream = fs.createReadStream('myFileToReadFrom'); 

// Every time readstream reads (Listen to stream events)
rstream.on('data', function (chunk) {
  // Advance your progress by chunk.length
  // progress += chunk.length 
});

rstream.on('end', function () {  // done
  // You finished reading rstream into wstream
});

rstream.pipe(wstream);
```

Be aware that this is async (non-blocking), so if you create a loop of readstreams, you would be trying to read/write all of your files at once

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck because I thought that reading might not be done at the same speed that writing, but as pipe manages the stream smartly, it may be accurate enough. I'm giving it a try right now !

Comment: Thanks ! I might edit your answer to add some more detail on how to get total size of file and display percentage of copy if you're OK with it :)

Comment: Yes, sure, feel free to add any relevant details! I thought of adding `fs.statSync()` to calcule progress for this single file example, but decided to leave it up to you.